# Finish proof of tautology

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm new to Discrete math, I've been working on this problem for near an hour and can't figure out the next steps. The problem is: Show that $[\neg p \land(p \lor q)] \to q$ is a tautology.

Here is what I have so far.
\begin{align}
\neg[\neg p \land(p \lor q)] \lor q 
&≡ [p \lor \neg(p \lor q)] \lor q \\
&≡ [p \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q)] \lor q \\
&≡ [(p \lor \neg p) \land (p \lor \neg q)] \lor q \\
&≡ [T \land (p \lor \neg q)] \lor q.
\end{align}

So at this point i'm not sure what to do with the $T$ or how I can get rid of the square brackets so that I can move on with the rest of the problem. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> ≡ [p ∨ (¬p ∨ ¬q)] ∨ q 
>   ≡ [(p ∨ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q)] ∨ q

Here is where you go wrong.  Note that all your binary connectives are disjunctions, so you can drop parentheses from [p ∨ (¬p ∨ ¬q)] ∨ q and get:

$p \lor \neg p \lor \neg q \lor q \equiv$

$\top \lor \top \equiv$

$\top$

If you are not allow to drop parentheses and use generalized disjunctions, then proceed as follows:

$[p \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q)] \lor q \equiv \text{ (Association)}$

$[(p \lor \neg p) \lor \neg q] \lor q \equiv \text{ (Complement)}$

$[\top \lor \neg q] \lor q \equiv \text{ (Annihilation)}$

$\top \lor q \equiv \text{ (Annihilation)}$

$\top$

Answer (score 0):

The transition between the third and the fourth line should be [p ∨ (¬p ∨ ¬q)] ∨ q $\iff$ [(p ∨ ¬p) ∨ ¬q] ∨ q. Then, you'll have a $T$ chained together with a bunch of "or"s, and that $T$ will consume them all.